# Android using vector drawable for image in customview with android < 5

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have a `CustomView` class with a `TextView` and a `ImageView` like

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    private ImageView imgImage;
    ...

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }
    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, this, true);
        imgImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomViewStyle);
        Drawable drawable = ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomViewStyle_image); // CRASH LINE

        ta.recycle();
        imgImage.setBackground(drawable);
    }
}
```

in `style.xml`

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomViewStyle">
     <attr format="string" name="text"/>
     <attr format="reference" name="image"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

build.gradle

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

When I using it like

```
<.CustomView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:image="@drawable/ic_android_black" //ic_android_black is a vector drawable
        />
```

it will throw a `Exception` in android 4.4, it work well from android 5

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_android_black.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f060054
```

How to make vector work in custom view with android < 5? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `VectorDrawableCompat.create(Resources, int, Theme)` to obtain a `VectorDrawableCompat` instance (which is a subclass of `Drawable`). Taking the code you posted as a template, you could write something like this:

```
TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomViewStyle);
int drawableId = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomViewStyle_image, 0);
ta.recycle();
if(drawableId != 0){
    Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), drawableId, null);
}
```

Note that you could pass the `Context` object from your constructor into this method and then use `context.getTheme()` instead of `null` for the third argument to `create()`.